# How to register Handlers when implementing CQRS with Aspnet Core Identiy

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, mediatr

I am trying to register, my users, using CQRS.

I am registering MediatR:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(MyCommand).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);


public class Handler : IRequestHandler<RegisterCommand, object>
        {
            private readonly MyDbContext _context;
            private readonly IMediator _mediator;
            private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

            public Handler(IYawaMVPDbContext context, IMediator mediator, UserManager<User> userManager)
            {
                _context = context;
                _mediator = mediator;
                _userManager = userManager;
            }
}
```

I am getting the following exceptions:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'MyDbContext' while attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[MyCore.Domain.Entities.User,MyCore.MyApp.Persistence.MyDbContext,System.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String]]'.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain,
>   ParameterInfo[] parameters, bool throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
>
> InvalidOperationException: Error constructing handler for request of
>   type
>   MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[MyCore.MyApp.Application.Users.Commands.Register.RegisterCommand,System.Object].

Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add service to resolve the DbContext in the startup file

```
services.AddDbContext<IYawaMVPDbContext, YourDbContextImplementation>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("yourConnectionString")));
```

Comment: I actually have this on the startup file. Distinctly I use MySql `services.AddDbContext<IYawaMVPDbContext, YawaMVPDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YawaMVPDatabase")));`

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code has no issue

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(MyCommand).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

handles all the MediatR IRequest and IRequestHandlers.

but you created an IYawaMVPDbContext  interface and its implementation class which can't be handled by that `MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`

DBContext are registered with dependency injection during application startup so that they can be provided automatically to components that consume services - manually register this like

`services.AddDbContext<IYawaMVPDbContext, DbContextImplementation>(options =>`                 `options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));`

Comment: your answer is already posted, before post an answer check if you consider that previously answer can be improved, edit it and offer a better experience for the community

Comment: As @Zachdev said, the answer is the same. So I will write the same comment. I actually have this on the startup file `services.AddDbContext<IYawaMVPDbContext, YawaMVPDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YawaMVPDatabase")));`